# Wpf client and asp.net web app signalr Hub , save users logged in from wpf client in signalr server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, signalr

I am creating **SignalR** hub in asp.net web app. My wpf application is a client for this **SignalR** hub

I have login facility in my wpf application , I want to store this users on hub created in asp.net , so that I can send information to specific user.
I want to store two properties UserName and UserToken , the list of these properties in hub , How I can send this properties information to hub

I tried using Client.Caller but its not getting any value in connected or disconnected event on hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the user in your hub methods: there is a `User` instance property. For the token, I will assume it is in the request headers. You can access that in the hub `Context.Request.Headers` property. You don't need to store users to send data to them. Somewhere (not in a hub inheritor) you will have a line like this:

```
private static readonly Lazy<IHubContext> _hubCtx = new Lazy<IHubContext>(() => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>());

protected virtual Task SendReportToAll(Report r)
{
    return _hubCtx.Value.Clients.All.EventToTriggerOnClient(r);
}

protected virtual Task SendReportToUser(Report r, string username)
{
    return _hubCtx.Value.Clients.User(username).EventToTriggerOnClient(r);
}
```

Comment: i am using wpf application as a server and client .. i need to display the dynamic list which i get from one user to a specific user in my application.. i am scratching my head to acheive this,, though i stuck up in filtering.. can you advise me on this... Thanks..